# Suppress/Disable shipping option in paypal express checkout

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

I have implemented paypal checkout in my website. (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/)

Its working fine. My website is not allowing custom shipping address to customers. Instead Customers, needs to come to our office and collect the items they purchased. So I want to disable/hide the shipping address in the paypal payment popup.

I found an option of 'NOSHIPPING' variable to 1. But it seems deprecated and its SOAP method.

Is there anyway to disable shipping address change in paypal checkout payment popup.

Answer (score 0):

With the REST API you create [Experience Profiles](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/v1/) for this sort of thing.

You can build an Experience Profile with a Brand Name, logo, options for allowing notes, disabling shipping, etc.  So you could have separate profiles setup in different ways.

Then you can pass the profile ID you want to use into your checkout/payment accordingly.